# Flutter : I want to share title and main_img(dynamic data) when i click share icon using whats app and gmail?

Tags: flutter, image, share

eg :- details about the question ........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................ I want to share image and title using whatsapp and gmail. I tried with   url_launcher: ^5.4.2 and   share: ^0.5.3 but not working . when i click share icon to share title and image nothing happened. anyone help me. below i've mentioned the details page code please find and check that.

### Deatils Page :

```
 import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:odia_rasiphala/HomePage.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
import 'package:launch_review/launch_review.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsPage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title,
      required this.main_img,
      required this.eng_title,
      required this.content})
      : super(key: key);

  // Declare a field that holds the strings passed to this class.
  final String title;
  final String main_img;
  final String content;
  final String eng_title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('ଆଜିର ରାଶିଫଳ'),
            leading: new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {


                  ;
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(
                main_img,
                width: 200.0,
                height: 200.0,
              ),
      

              Text(title, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19)),
              Text(eng_title,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19)),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),

              Text("( " + "10 Feb 2022" + " )",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 19)),
              // Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0)),

              Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 30.0,
                    right: 30.0,
                    top: 15.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    content,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 17),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  )),

              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {

                },
                child: Container(
                    width: 300.00,
                    height: 150.00,
                    child: Image.network(
                      "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-R7wqNDfZ7H4/YgTuUsboyKI/AAAAAAAAAlQ/6UpZ7orQPdgLBkzwZeHmPN0V2z-tR38rgCNcBGAsYHQ/s0/wayindia.png?authuser=0",
                    )),
              )

           
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the premade plugin dependencies listed below, the `share` package is nor deprecated. You could either use [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) or [flutter_share](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share)